# Programmatically stream Android content to TV

Tags: android

What I would like to achieve is to live-stream one of my Android 
game to TV (using **DLNA/Wifi Direct** connection).
Can I somehow do that? I still would like to control my game using phone (as it is), 
but I would see my game screen on my TV in live.
Are there any solution out there?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked into Google Chromecast? https://developers.google.com/cast/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For Android 4.2+, your app can use a `Presentation` and `DisplayManager` (or `MediaRouter`) to show separate content on an external display (HDMI, MHL, SlimPort, Miracast). Miracast is based on WiFiDirect.

[Here is a presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/commonsguy/secondary-screen-support-with-displaymanager) that I delivered last year that covers this topic.

Comment: @Mark sir, is it similar to Google cast?

Comment: @RahulMatte: That depends on your definition of "similar". You may wish to ask a separate Stack Overflow question where you explain in greater detail what your concerns are.

Comment: thank you sir, here is my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31772186/playing-video-from-device-to-tv-on-lan