# Android programmatically stream video to TV via Wi-Fi

Tags: android, video, streaming, wifi, wifi-direct

I know that it's possible to stream a video from Android device to TV using technologies like Miracast or Wi-Fi direct. But is it possible to stream a video from Android App to TV programmatically while showing some another UI (not this video) on device at the same time? If yes, which technology or API could be used and what's the minimal supported Android version?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this post: [Programmatically stream Android content to TV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21940359/programmatically-stream-android-content-to-tv)

I have been experimenting heavily with this, but have yet to get it to work reliably.