# Playing video from device to TV on LAN

Tags: android, youtube

I don't know the name of this technology, the user can play videos from device to TV. It's available on the android Youtube app, see the image below. I want to add the same functionality in my app, I don't know from where I should start on this?[image]

Comment: the device (tv) you want your android to work on must be compatible, smart tv's / appletv/chrome cast can do this, if you dont have it your phone cant stream to tv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um, what you have circled is an icon in an action bar. While it represents "casting" some content from an app to a TV, there are any number of ways that "casting" can be implemented by an app. There is no single "technology" tied to that icon.

It can be:

- Using `RemotePlaybackClient`, to tell another device (e.g., a Chromecast) some media to play back, or
- Using the Google Cast SDK, a proprietary set of APIs that work only with Chromecast and Android TV, or
- Using some proprietary protocol of its own to tell another device some media to play back

Ignoring the icon, you can also use `Presentation` to display a separate UI on a TV from what you have on a phone or tablet. `Presentation` requires some sort of established connection to the external display, be that wired (HDMI, MHL, SlimPort, etc.) or wireless (Miracast, WiDi, etc.). Usually, there is no "cast" icon in an action bar for this case, as the app can automatically detect that it is connected to an external display and make use of it (e.g., play the video on it).

And, of course, there are Android-powered devices that connect directly to a TV (Fire TV, Fire TV Stick, Android TV, various "HDMI sticks" available on eBay/Alibaba/elsewhere, etc.). You would not have a "cast" icon in an action bar on those, as you already are displaying your UI on a TV.

Here are [slides from a half-day workshop](https://commonsware.com/presos/AnDevConSF2014-TV.pdf) that I delivered last year on the various options for getting your app to display content on a TV.

Comment: @CommonsWare https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51246868/mediarouter-and-presentation-api-android-on-miracast-deviceanycast

Answer (score 1):

Its called Google Chromecast see the link below : http://www.google.com/chrome/devices/chromecast/